# Iterating through Javascript object and count

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have this javascript object. How can iterate through its properties and count the number of one specific value?

```
    angular.module('App',[])
        .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

           var data = {  
   "plans":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_500gm",
         "name":"Next Day less than 500gm",
         "cost":55,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":0,
         "max_weight":500,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_500gm_1kg",
         "name":"Next Day 500gm to 1kg",
         "cost":70,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":501,
         "max_weight":1000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_1kg_2kg",
         "name":"Next Day 1kg to 2kg",
         "cost":95,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":1001,
         "max_weight":2000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_500gm",
         "name":"Same Day less than 500gm",
         "cost":95,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":0,
         "max_weight":500,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":5,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_500gm_1kg",
         "name":"Same Day 500gm to 1kg",
         "cost":130,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":501,
         "max_weight":1000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":6,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_1kg_2kg",
         "name":"Same Day 1kg to 2kg",
         "cost":165,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":1001,
         "max_weight":2000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      }
   ]
};  
          $scope.data1=data;       
       }]);
```

My concept is i want to count how many times the "status" field is "COMPLETE"and assign that count in a variable. Say if the complete is 4 times my sale will be equal to 4. How can i do that? Any hint?

Comment: `var count = 0; data.forEach(function(item){ if(item.status === "COMPLETE") {count++}  }); if(count===4){....}`

Comment: where is status field in your objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 23,
  "sender_id": 3,
  "courier_id": 0,
  "deliverer_id": 0,
  "status": "PENDING",
  "consignment_id": "55C0A999",
  "sender_name": "asdasdas d",
  "cost": "40",
  "package_description": "asdasdasd",
  "sender_address": "asdasdasd",
  "sender_longitude": "",
  "sender_latitude": "",
  "sender_number": null,
  "receiver_address": "adasdasd",
  "receiver_name": "Shifat Adnan",
  "receiver_number": "01713206053",
  "receiver_longitude": "",
  "receiver_latitude": "",
  "current_longitude": "",
  "current_latitude": "",
  "deliverer": null,
  "recipient_pays": 0,
  "instructions": "2332323",
  "payment_status": null,
  "cod": 0,
  "recipient_zone_id": 2,
  "plan_id": 2,
  "store_id": null,
  "storeproduct_id": null,
  "created_at": "2015-08-04 12:01:29"
}, {
  "id": 28,
  "sender_id": 5,
  "courier_id": 0,
  "deliverer_id": 0,
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "consignment_id": "10F317",
  "sender_name": "bleh",
  "cost": "398",
  "package_description": "Business Order",
  "sender_address": "bleh",
  "sender_longitude": "bleh",
  "sender_latitude": "bleh",
  "sender_number": "bleh",
  "receiver_address": "kjakdjlsdjlaksdjl",
  "receiver_name": "Nigga",
  "receiver_number": "010203001",
  "receiver_longitude": "",
  "receiver_latitude": "",
  "current_longitude": "bleh",
  "current_latitude": "bleh",
  "deliverer": null,
  "recipient_pays": 0,
  "instructions": "jslklsdflkj",
  "payment_status": null,
  "cod": 0,
  "recipient_zone_id": null,
  "plan_id": 4,
  "store_id": null,
  "storeproduct_id": null,
  "created_at": "2015-10-04 09:36:23"
}, {
  "id": 34,
  "sender_id": 5,
  "courier_id": 0,
  "deliverer_id": 0,
  "status": "PENDING",
  "consignment_id": "137F24",
  "sender_name": "bleh",
  "cost": "3223",
  "package_description": "Business Order",
  "sender_address": "bleh",
  "sender_longitude": "bleh",
  "sender_latitude": "bleh",
  "sender_number": "bleh",
  "receiver_address": "kasdlkaskd asldka",
  "receiver_name": "FAAskl",
  "receiver_number": "199102909",
  "receiver_longitude": "",
  "receiver_latitude": "",
  "current_longitude": "bleh",
  "current_latitude": "bleh",
  "deliverer": null,
  "recipient_pays": 0,
  "instructions": "dsdsdf",
  "payment_status": null,
  "cod": 0,
  "recipient_zone_id": 2,
  "plan_id": 3,
  "store_id": null,
  "storeproduct_id": null,
  "created_at": "2015-10-06 07:58:28"
}, {
  "id": 35,
  "sender_id": 5,
  "courier_id": 0,
  "deliverer_id": 0,
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "consignment_id": "13C476",
  "sender_name": "bleh",
  "cost": "3310",
  "package_description": "Business Order",
  "sender_address": "bleh",
  "sender_longitude": "bleh",
  "sender_latitude": "bleh",
  "sender_number": "bleh",
  "receiver_address": "sdfs dfasdfasdfasdf",
  "receiver_name": "sfasd",
  "receiver_number": "224",
  "receiver_longitude": "",
  "receiver_latitude": "",
  "current_longitude": "bleh",
  "current_latitude": "bleh",
  "deliverer": null,
  "recipient_pays": 0,
  "instructions": "dasdasd",
  "payment_status": null,
  "cod": 0,
  "recipient_zone_id": 2,
  "plan_id": 1,
  "store_id": 1,
  "storeproduct_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2015-10-06 12:54:14"
}, {
  "id": 36,
  "sender_id": 5,
  "courier_id": 0,
  "deliverer_id": 0,
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "consignment_id": "13C4B3",
  "sender_name": "bleh",
  "cost": "330",
  "package_description": "Business Order",
  "sender_address": "bleh",
  "sender_longitude": "bleh",
  "sender_latitude": "bleh",
  "sender_number": "bleh",
  "receiver_address": "sdfs dfasdfasdfasdf",
  "receiver_name": "Some full name",
  "receiver_number": "224",
  "receiver_longitude": "",
  "receiver_latitude": "",
  "current_longitude": "bleh",
  "current_latitude": "bleh",
  "deliverer": null,
  "recipient_pays": 0,
  "instructions": "dasdasd",
  "payment_status": null,
  "cod": 0,
  "recipient_zone_id": 3,
  "plan_id": 4,
  "store_id": 1,
  "storeproduct_id": 2,
  "created_at": "2015-10-06 12:55:15"
}];
var count = 0;
data.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.status === 'COMPLETED') {
    ++count;
  }
});
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use filter here:

```
var count = data.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.status === 'COMPLETED';
}).length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: a flexible fork: `function compare(obj){return obj[this[0]]===this[1]; }; ...  dones=data.filter(compare, ['status', 'COMPLETED']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your `json` object like this:

```
var complete = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    if (obj['status'] == "COMPLETE"){
        complete += 1;
    }
}
//do something with complete.
```

Comment: Just one small amendment: You should use `===` instead of `==`. It's always safer to use strict comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0, leng = data.plans.length; i < leng; i++)
    {
        if (data.plans[i].status === 'COMPLETE')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count === 4)
    {

    }
```